# onclick event and json data not meshing together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a silly error which I cant seem to fix some how. I'm simply looking to do the following:

```
onclick="CreatePro('x','y','z')"
```

I basically want to pass text to the CreatePro function. Now my values of x,y and z are json data. As such here is what I am using for the javascript:

```
var Provision =  "'" + data[i].ProvisionID  + "'";
var Title = "'" + data[i].Title + "'";
var Author = "'" + data[i].Author + "'";
var Edition = "'" + data[i].Edition + "'";
var Publisher = "'" + data[i].Publisher+ "'";
var ISBN =  "'" + data[i].ISBN + "'";
var UserID = "'"  +data[i].UserID + "'";
var Price = "'" + data[i].Price+ "'";
var Condition = "'"  +data[i].Condition +"'";

Row = Row + "<td><input type='button' onclick='CreatePro(" + Provision + "," + Title+ "," + Author + "," + Edition + "," + Publisher  +"," + ISBN  + ","+ UserID + ","+ Price + "," + Condition + ")' value='Create'></td></tr>";
console.log(Row);
```

Now when I use console.log I get the following:

```
<td><input type='button' onclick='CreatePro('19','dfjeryj','ertj','0','tj','0000000000000','4','0','0')' value='Create'></td>
```

But when I inspect the element I have :

```
<input type="button" onclick="CreatePro(" 19','dfjeryj','ertj','0','tj','0000000000000','4','0','0')'="" value="Create">
```

The problem is suspect is the " on the above line. But I dont know why this is happening? As from the console log. My quotes seem to match up. So I'm not sure why the browser is mixing them up? Perhaps I've gone wrong somewhere? (Frankly I can;t see the error). Every time I click the create button the event doesn't call my CreatePro function. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong or perhaps a better way of doing what I'm doing

Comment: How to avoid this problem altogether: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got your quotes wrong. It should be:

```
Row = Row + "<td><input type='button' onclick=\"CreatePro('" + Provision + "','" + Title+ "','" + Author + "','" + Edition + "','" + Publisher  +"','" + ISBN  + "','"+ UserID + "','"+ Price + "','" + Condition + "')\" value='Create'></td></tr>";
```